# How do I pass these integers to the method below it?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, multiple-instances

I'm confusing myself here. My goal was to make a simple program that took the number of values the user wants to average, store them in an array (while adding them together) and finally giving the average of these numbers.

My thing is, I am trying to understand the concept of multiple classes and methods as I am new so I tried using another class just do do all the work, while the Main class would just create the object from the other class, and then run their methods. Maybe I am asking something impossible. Take a look at my code.

This is my Main class:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers to average together");

        OtherClass averages = new OtherClass();
        averages.collectNumbers();
        averages.AverageNumbers();
    }
}
```

Now I am not sure if anything goes in those parameters, or if I can even use "averages.AverageNumbers();" without creating another object with "OtherClass" called something else? I am pretty sure it's legal though.

Here is my other class for this project entitled "OtherClass"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OtherClass // using this to name obj
{
    public void collectNumbers() //name of our method that does things
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("how many integers would you like to average? ");
        int givenNum = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Alright, I will average " + givenNum + " values. \nPress   enter after each:");

        int[] numCollect = new int[givenNum];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numCollect.length; i++)
        {
            numCollect[i] = sc.nextInt();
            sum = sum + numCollect[i];
        }
        System.out.println(sum);


    }
    public int AverageNumbers(int givenNum, int sum)
    {
        int average = sum / givenNum;
        System.out.println(average);
        return average;
    }
}
```

So when I run this now with the the method AverageNumbers, it does not work.  I am suspecting that maybe I am passing in the integers wrong? I have been toying with it for about an hour now, so I am asking for help. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work if you declare `sum` and `givenNum` as fields of your `OtherClass`, instead of as local variables.  So, before the `collectNumbers` method, write

```
private int sum;
private int givenNum;
```

and remove the declarations of these two variables inside `collectNumbers`. So, for example, instead of

```
int givenNum = sc.getInt();
```

you'll just have

```
givenNum = sc.getInt();
```

because the variable already exists.  Also change the declaration of the `averageNumbers` method to

```
public int averageNumbers()
```

because you no longer need to pass those two values in to this method.

This is the archetypical example of using the objects of a class to carry a small amount of data around, instead of just using a class as a way to group methods together.  The two methods of this class work with `sum` and `givenNum`, so it makes sense to store these in each object of this class.

Lastly, in your `averageNumbers` method, you have an integer division, which will automatically round down.  You probably want a floating point division instead, so you could write

```
double average = (double) sum / givenNum;
```

which converts `sum` to a double-precision floating point number before the division, and therefore does the division in floating point, instead of just using integers.  Of course, if you make this change, you'll need to change the return type of this method to `double` too.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked. I now understand that both of these variables belong to my OtherClass class. Can you explain to me my variables must be private now?

Comment: Well, they don't HAVE to be `private`, but it's good practice to make a field or a method `private` if it's not going to be used outside the class where it's declared.  There are lots of reasons for this, but one really good reason is so that if you encounter a problem where one of those variables doesn't have the value that you expect it to have, then you only have to look in ONE class for your problem, rather than the entire program.

Comment: Understood. This might be a little too much to ask of you, but how would you make this program? Obviously as someone more experienced than I am, you know a lot more. I know it is only a simple averaging program, but I am curious to know. (Could be just be explanation, not expecting you to code me a whole program :)). Thanks for all the help!